# React - How to resolve: "JSX expression must have parent and expression expected" error in vs code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple App.js file which is rendering fine in the browser but I am getting some problems or errors in the VS code editor.

I am getting these errors -

[image]

My App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import css from "./App.less";
import DonutChart from "./DonutChart";
import TimeLineChart from "./TimeLineChart";
import DataTable from "./DataTable";
import SidebarSample from "./SidebarSample";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    let panelLeftCss = css.panel;
    panelLeftCss += " " + css.leftPanel;

    let panelRightCss = css.panel;
    panelRightCss += " " + css.rightPanel;
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="header">
            <div>
              <h1>Welcome Admin, My Dashboard</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <SidebarSample />
          </div>

          <div className={css.main}>
            <div className={panelLeftCss}>
              <div className={css.panelHeader}>Donut Chart</div>
              <div className={css.panelBody}>
                <div>
                  <DonutChart />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className={panelRightCss}>
              <div className={css.panelHeader}>Line Chart</div>
              <div className={css.panelBody}>
                <div>
                  <TimeLineChart />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div className={css.panelHeader}>Data Table</div>
            <div>
              <DataTable />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have tried to add a `<React.Fragment>` also but it's not resolving the errors in the VS code editor.

Is there any tool that I can use which solves this automatically, like prettier etc?

Please guide me.

Comment: The render method in App.js is returning only one parent div which is perfectly fine. just check the render function of SidebarSample, DonutChart, TimeLineChart and DataTable.

Comment: I tried to check on [EsLint](https://eslint.org/demo/) it is not throwing such error with given code

Comment: @GopalSharma i checked for all it's only returning single div for all.

Comment: @CodeManiac I can understand, but my VS code shows some error.

Comment: CHECK YOUR FILE EXTENSION .ts .js MUST BE .tsx or .jsx

Answer (score 1):

Check your file extension its `.ts`
It must be `.tsx`(if you're using TypeScript)
Same for `App.js` change it to `App.jsx` (if you're using JavaScript)
then,
try this,
all your code must be in single parent tag, like i did inside `<div>`
as when render method returns only single parent, so you must careful while writing elements having only one parent or you wrap your code inside parent `<div>`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import css from "./App.less";
import DonutChart from "./DonutChart";
import TimeLineChart from "./TimeLineChart";
import DataTable from "./DataTable";
import SidebarSample from "./SidebarSample";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    let panelLeftCss = css.panel;
    panelLeftCss += " " + css.leftPanel;

    let panelRightCss = css.panel;
    panelRightCss += " " + css.rightPanel;
    return (
    <div>
    <div className="header">
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome Admin, My Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <SidebarSample />
    </div>

    <div className={css.main}>
        <div className={panelLeftCss}>
            <div className={css.panelHeader}>Donut Chart</div>
            <div className={css.panelBody}>
                <div>
                    <DonutChart />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className={panelRightCss}>
            <div className={css.panelHeader}>Line Chart</div>
            <div className={css.panelBody}>
                <div>
                    <TimeLineChart />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div className={css.panelHeader}>Data Table</div>
            <div>
                <DataTable />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it's same what i have, even i am returning the single div.

Comment: Your file extension is `.ts` change it to `.tsx` please

Answer (score 0):

Prettier or any other code formatting tools won't help you if you do not enclose your div with tags properly. 
You forgot your closing `</div>` tag at the end of your code.
Also you have an extra `</div>` tag near your `<TimeLineChart>` there.
Check the formatted codes here as below. It should work. 
You just need to be more careful in placing the tags.

```
<div>
    <div className="header">
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome Admin, My Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <SidebarSample />
    </div>

    <div className={css.main}>
        <div className={panelLeftCss}>
            <div className={css.panelHeader}>Donut Chart</div>
            <div className={css.panelBody}>
                <div>
                    <DonutChart />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className={panelRightCss}>
            <div className={css.panelHeader}>Line Chart</div>
            <div className={css.panelBody}>
                <div>
                    <TimeLineChart />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div className={css.panelHeader}>Data Table</div>
            <div>
                <DataTable />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think there’s any extra div i have validated.

Comment: Its about file extensions